# Trouble setting up a subdomain on a VPS under Ubuntu and Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, subdomain, vps

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to servers, so I need some help.  Basically, I want to have a subdomain on my VPS. I'm not too concerned where the files reside, though of course I would like them separated if possible.

I found a [guide](http://brucewampler.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/adding-virtual-hosts-to-ubuntu-apache/) to doing this that basically sums the procedure up in five steps:

> 1. Create directories to host the content of a new virtual site.
>
>    1. Make a copy of the /etc/apache2/sites-available/defaults file with a site appropriate name.
>    2. Change the two /var/www/ entries to the actual directory of the new site.
>    3. Add the ServerName line with the real domain name you will be hosting.
>    4. Use a2ensite to enable the new site, and finally reload Apache2 so it knows about the new site

I tried all of this, but I can't get it to work. I didn't get any errors at any point during this process, but when I enter the address with the subdomain into my browser, I get a "Server not found" error.

The company that hosts my VPS has an admin page where I can set up subdomains. Stupid question: do I have to do reconfigure the DNS records or something while doing this, or is it likely that the problem is caused by something else?

Additional note: I followed a guide on howtoforge.com when setting up the server, which in hindsight may not have been the brightest move on my part. It is possible that I made a mistake there that is somehow affecting me now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've setup the subdomain correctly in your VPS' admin page, the only thing left to check here is that you've actually *created* the subdomain in your DNS administration page (have you?). For example, I use afraid.org to manage my DNS records and to add a subdomain, it's essentially:

```
Type: A
Subdomain: sparky
Domain: example.com
Destination: 120.34.2.3 (this would be your VPS' IP address)
```

In general, you add a (sub)domain by:

```
sparky.example.com A 120.34.2.3
```

Please keep in mind that you want to add an `A` record (*this is important!*).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  My hosting company has a page for handling DNS and stuff, so I've gone and added another A record like you said, and pointed it to the same IP address.

Another question: will it take some time for the change to take effect, or should it be instantaneous?  My browser still can't find the subdomain...

Comment: @blainarmstrong: The general rule of thumb is that DNS propagations (around the world) take about 24hrs - although in practice, you should start seeing results within an hour or two. A good way to check is to do `nslookups` from different points on the globe but I wouldn't bother. Everything should be fine.

Comment: This is why I come to stackoverflow.com: people really are helpful.  Thank you. I'll check back in a couple of hours to see if the new subdomain takes.

Comment: Update: I tried the subdomain and it works. As they say over here, 誠にありがとうございました m(_)m